# Bootstrap 5 carousel-caption text disappears when the website is seen on a smaller screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap carousal code. My carousal text looks good when seen on the regular size but it disappears when seen on the smaller size screen. It seems the text is getting behind the image. I have tried using z-index, media query for changing font sizes, margins, paddings but it still the same.

HTML code:

```
  <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-light slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-indicators">
  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
</div>
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000">
    <img src="images/image1.jpeg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <h1>First slide lable</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
    <img src="images/image2.jpeg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <h1>Second slide lable</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="images/image3.jpeg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <h1>Third slide label</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
</button>
<button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
</button>
```

CSS code:

```
.carousel-caption {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 18%;
  z-index: 999;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
  padding-top: 20%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.carousel-caption {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the classes `d-none d-md-block` on the captions. This effectively puts `display: none` from `xs` and then `display: block` from `md` and above. Remove all 3 `d-none` and your issue will be solved.

Change:

```
<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    // caption
</div>
```

To:

```
<div class="carousel-caption">
    // caption
</div>
```

Edit: You actually do not need `d-md-block` either, given the element is blocked by default.